# Which way works to put a PDF in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I need a method that really works in IE, Chrome and Firefox to show a PDF in an iframe. I can not use google docs GView to do this... I need another method that is 100% functional. Give me some example please guys... I've tried PDFJS and PDFObject, but they do not work.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I doubt the only really cross-browser way would be to convert the pdf to HTML on server-side, and then load that HTML.

Comment: Realized you did not want to use PDFObject... is this because it didn't work or what?

Comment: i tried this but not work for me in my ie 11 and chrome https://www.dropbox.com/s/rcwvngdghnczn6a/teste.rar?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

[PDF Object](http://pdfobject.com/) works to create a view of a pdf in an object. You can create an object, and reference it to an id:

HTML:

JavaScript:

```
var pdf = new PDFObject({
    url: "sample.pdf",
    id: "object",
    pdfOpenParams: {
          view: "FitH"
    }
}).embed("object")
```

Works cross browser! You just need to include PDF Object code in your project.

Comment: i tried this but not work for me in my ie 11 and chrome https://www.dropbox.com/s/rcwvngdghnczn6a/teste.rar?dl=0